# Application Start Before Windows Explorer

Tags: windows, startup, windows-explorer

Some installation applications stop (or appear to stop) the normal windows booting. The computer starts, the user logs in and then the installation program starts before others (like Windows explorer).

How can I replicate this behaviour in my own program?

*E.g.*

- OS Boot
- Login
- The program runs, updates etc.
- The rest of the programs run (e.g. windows explorer and what ever runs on startup)

Comment: What do you want this app to do before explorer starts?

Comment: The app will check for updates, install a few files, prompt the user for information and then continue with the operating system start.

Comment: That's **not** what those install programs do. If you tell us what you're trying to accomplish, surely someone can tell you a better way of doing it than trying to preempt Windows Explorer.

Comment: To create a program that runs before anything else has started - so the user has logged in, nothing (e.g. startup programs / explorer has started yet). The program will then run. Once it has finished, everything else that normally loads would be loaded - e.g. windows explorer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have not tried it but I assume that this is done by the registry entry

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce\Setup
```

There are even more registry keys - see the complete list documented here: 
[Definition of the RunOnce Keys in the Registry](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/137367/en-us)

But for your use case I would recommend to start your application as desktop shell similar to the proposed solution by "vcsjones". When your program has finished you can call `explorer.exe` to start loading the regular desktop.

Answer (score 12):

If you want to start an application before the shell starts, you can add a value to the `Userinit` value in the registry. In this key:

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon

There is a value named `Userinit`. Change it so your program is run before userinit.exe. For example, to start notepad before the shell/everything else is initialized:

> C:\WINDOWS\system32\notepad.exe,C:\Windows\system32\userinit.exe

Use commas to separate the programs that should be started.

This works for Windows XP, Vista, and 7.

Comment: You typically will get 'Access Denied' and all antiviruses will ban the application.

Comment: According to this [tutorial](http://www.tenouk.com/ModuleP1.html) the explorer run key is set just before userinit. However [this ancient article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/142905) states USERINIT is responsible for launching the explorer shell. On newer systems this is still the [case](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc939862.aspx).

Comment: Actually tried this method but it [didn't work on W7](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/c810e785-894e-4b4f-be72-a12e35397126/running-a-program-at-startup?forum=windowsgeneraldevelopmentissues&prof=required). But does anyone here know if it worked for pre Vista?

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at Windows [Task Scheduler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383614%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Tasks can be scheduled to execute when a user (specific or any) logs on. The UI provided out-of-the-box by Windows illustrates what can actually be done with this standard Windows feature.

Another solution is to write a [Windows service](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_service) (the .msi Windows Installer is in fact a service).

I'm not sure you will be able to *block* Windows Explorer though...

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly wrap a windows batch file `.bat` around `explorer.exe`

```
@echo off
something.exe
explorer.exe
```

But that wouldn't really make sure it's always started before explorer.exe

You could possibly change some registry value to select another 'shell' instead of explorer for that . .

If that is what you are actually looking for.